# Upgraded SSMS and now Redgate tools are missing

Tags: ssms, redgate

I recently upgraded to SSMS 2016 and the Redgate tools I have for 2014 are still there but missing in 2016.  Do i need to uninstall and reinstall Redgate?  If so do i need to deactivate my key before doing so?  Does anyone know of a way to attach the tools with out a reinstall?

Comment: Only solution that seems to work according to [RedGate Forums - Install on SSMS 2017](https://forum.red-gate.com/discussion/80973/install-on-ssms-2017) is to **Uninstall & Re-install** Toolbelt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to reactivate if you're using the same machine. Installing the tools afresh should just work.

But as a precaution make sure you take a note of your serial number and contact support@red-gate.com if you have any problems.

Comment: I had to uninstall the tools then reinstall them. That is what i wast trying to avoid but there was no way around it.  Thanks for the repy.